# jquery; create link similar to rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This may be a daft question but I'm trying to replicate a link that I've created in rails but in jquery.

Rails link;

```
<%= link_to 'unfollow', dashboard_follow_index_path(blog: n['blog_name']), method: :post, remote: true, class: 'f-button' %>
```

output;

```
<a class="f-button" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/dashboard/follow?blog=b">unfollow</a>
```

What I've got in jquery so far;

```
var newLink = $("<a />", {
          class : "f-button",
          href : "I know how to get this blog name.",
          method : "post",
          rel : "nofollow",
          text : "follow",
        });
```

Output;

```
<a rel="nofollow" method="post" href="/dashboard/follow?blog=b" id="f-button">follow</a>
```

The links don't work the same;

Comment: RoR does a lot of Javascript behind the scenes. Without that, the link would never be able to POST. You can replicate it in jQuery, look at `jQuery.post()`

Answer (score 0):

**Using JQuery**

```
var newLink = $("<a />", {
      'class' : 'f-button',
      name : "link",
      href : "you know how to get this blog name.",
      method : "post",
      rel : "nofollow",
      text : "follow"
});
```

Comment: This isn't what I was after. I want to create the link in jQuery not html.

Comment: Copy paste my code it should work for you. You were adding comma after text : "follow"

Comment: How about the data attributes?

Comment: you can pass attributes to a self-closed element, If you want to generate a class name on the fly with your dynamically generated <a>, you may need to put single quotes around class, in order for things to work in IE7, and IE8 - for example 'class':'f-button'

Comment: Hi - would you know what the href would be if all you know is the relative path name?